# Twemproxy key distribution

Tags: hash, twemproxy, libketama

How twemproxy uses hash function and keys distribution method to decide which key will go to which shard?
Is there any in which lib or code i can use to specify which hash function to use and given set of servers, can it tell which shard it will go to?
(mine uses distribution - ketama and hash - fnv1a_64 )

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you got a better document where the kinds of twemproxy distributions means..?

Comment: No, i searched for this but nothing much.